# Creating an IntegrationRuntimeResource for DatafactoryV2 fails with BadRequest

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-factory

I'm having some issues with the new Datafactory management API. When creating a IRM, i get a BadRequest, with no explanation on whats wrong.

Small code sample below. Any suggestions to what might be wrong?

```
  private async Task<IntegrationRuntimeResource> GetOrCreateIntegrationRuntime(string irmName)
    {
        Log.Information("Creating IntegrationRuntime Resource with name {IrmName}", irmName);

        var irmResource = new IntegrationRuntimeResource(new IntegrationRuntime(), type: IntegrationRuntimeType.SelfHosted, name: irmName);
        return await AzureServiceFactory.GetDatafactoryManagementClient().IntegrationRuntimes
            .CreateOrUpdateAsync(Config.ResourceGroupName, EnvironmentSettings.Datafactory.Name,
                irmName, irmResource);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured i'd pull out fiddler and use Martin's example to figure out what is was missing. Turns out even though API allows for specifying the type of IRM, it completely ignores it. The type of the Integrationruntime is serialized as the type.

So - the code for updating an IRM is as follows.

```
public async Task<IntegrationRuntimeResource> CreateorUpdateIntegrationRuntime(string irmName)
        {
            Log.Information("Creating IntegrationRuntime Resource with name {IrmName}", irmName);
            var irmResource = new IntegrationRuntimeResource(new SelfHostedIntegrationRuntime(),
                type: IntegrationRuntimeType.SelfHosted, // this is ignored by the API but persisted for my sanity (or an api upgrade)
                name: irmName);
            return await AzureServiceFactory.GetDatafactoryManagementClient().IntegrationRuntimes
                .CreateOrUpdateAsync(Config.ResourceGroupName, EnvironmentSettings.Datafactory.Name,
                    irmName, irmResource);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using the .net library you dont get any explanation when an error occurs, what I do in those cases is try creating it from powershell to get more details about the error, you can add -Verbose at the end of the command to get a step by step from the shell.

A basic script to create an IR from powershell is:

```
$SubscriptionName = ""
$ResourceGroupName = ""
$DataFactoryName = ""
$DataFactoryLocation = "eastus2" 
$SelfHostedIntegrationRuntimeName = ""

Login-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName

Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $SelfHostedIntegrationRuntimeName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Type SelfHosted -Location $DataFactoryLocation
```

Fill with the values and execute it, it will make you login, then will choose the subscription and finally will try creating the integration runtime. If you still get the error remember to add -Verbose at the end of the last command.

Cheers!

Edit: just remembered that the location is a must-have value! your code is probably failing because of that, because the library doesnt specify this. Im not entirely sure if this applies to SelfHosted IRs, but it surely is a must for Managed type IRs.